# Vuejs does not update the DOM if the data is fetched over HTTPS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a fetch method that gets some realtime data **streams** from an API endpoint and the Vue app displays them in real-time in a component.

Everything works perfectly fine if I use HTTP. However, **If I switch to HTTPS** on the backend, **Vuje does not update the components** while receiving the stream.

It only updates the DOM, if I manually terminate the https connection from the backend. At that point, it will update the DOM and display the fetched data.
Here is the code:

```js
mounted() {

        //If I use HTTPS here, Vue does not update the DOM in realtime 
         fetch("https://example.com/api")
          .then(response => {
            return ndjsonStream(response.body);
          })
          .then(stream => {
            const reader = stream.getReader();
            let read;
            reader.read().then(
              (read = result => {
                if (result.done) {
                  return;
                }
                reader.read().then(read);
                this.recentPrice = result.value;
                this.prices.push(result.value);               
              })
            );
          });
        }
```

I have also tried this.$forceUpdate() but it did not work. On the backend, I have Nginx and Express(). Also, the HTTPS connection seems to work fine for other non Vue.js applications. Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: We nees more information, like request headers and response

Comment: Here are the headers:

Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
Content-Type: application/x-ndjson
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection:keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Express

Comment: Add a catch handler to your function chain, and you'll probably see the cause of the error in your console:  `fetch(...).then(...).then(...).catch(console.error)`

Comment: Already did that. no errors at all.

Comment: are you handling the stream anywhere else?  did you put breakpoints to check if it ever reaches "done", and if not how far into the stream it gets stuck?  also, it doesn't look like from the code that you actually need streams?

Comment: This is a live dashboard so, for as long as the user keeps the dashboard open it keeps receiving the data. I need the stream because I want to receive the new data as soon as it becomes available on the backend and keep the connection alive. 
It might never reach "done", because here we are not fetching a fixed size file. It is unlimited data(generated in real-time) source and we can keep receiving the data for as long as we want. 
The point to note is the same logic works perfectly fine in HTTP mode but not in HTTPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I was able to solve the problem. The issue was due to the buffering of response chunks by Nginx.

Setting the proxy_buffering to off in the Nginx config file solved the issue.

```html
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;

  location /api {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    proxy_buffering off;
  }
}
```

I was using Nginx as a reverse proxy server and by default, the proxy buffering is on.

> When buffering is enabled, Nginx receives a response from the proxied
>   server as soon as possible but saves it into the buffers before
>   returning to the clients. However, When buffering is disabled, the
>   response is passed to a client synchronously, immediately as it is
>   received. nginx will not try to read the whole response from the
>   proxied server.

So essentially that was the reason that I was not receiving my data chunks immediately in the app.